# Thread populating collection and Java memory model

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I noticed that If I let a thread populate a collection, at the end of the thread after the `join`, I see the collection populated as expected.

In respect to the Java memory model, is this always guaranteed to happen ?

what if the thread is storing the references of the objects in the list in the cpu cache ?
In this case after the join the joining thread would have to guarantee to see the changes ?

```
final ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList();
Thread myThread = new MyThread(persons);
myThread.start();
myThread.join();

// persons ?
```

Thread

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    
    ArrayList<Person> persons;

    public MyThread(ArrayList<Person> persons){
     this.persons = persons;
    }

    public void run(){
      persons.add(new Person(...))
      // add more
    }
  }
```

Comment: `join`ing a Thread establishes a happens-before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed by the memory model.

- There is a *happens before* between the `start()` call and the first action of the child thread's `run()` method.
- There is a *happens before* between the last action (of any kind) of the child thread and the `join()` returning in the parent thread.

This is specified in [JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

These are sufficient to ensure that the child thread sees a properly initialized list and the parent thread sees a correctly populated list ... after the `join()`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java Language Specification § 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> ...
> All actions in a thread *happen-before* any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.
> ...